# Detecting GO key on keyboard, and popping to top of nav stack

Tags: iphone

I am trying to implement signup/login via a nav controller for my iphone app.

My issue is I need to detect the GO button and pop to the nav root.  Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"RETURN KEY HIT!");
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"email = %@", emailTextField.text);
    NSLog(@"pw = %@", passwordTextField.text);
    [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];
    return YES;
}
```

GO does cause this method to be called, but the nav controller doesn't pop.  I'm not surprised as the method returns a BOOL so it's obviously not designed for this use.

So what is the correct way to handle detecting a GO and acting on it?

Thanks!

[alt text http://grab.by/2SnU](http://grab.by/2SnU)

Comment: Are you sure that your navigationController is not null?
Because usually I use this same process for swithcing view to another.

Comment: aha!  I'm used to java where you get a NPE when there is a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple.  as Yannick L suggested I had a null for my nav.  Duh :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];